# Multi graph with Seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot four different barplots, and I'd like to have them in the same line. Particularly, I want four plots as the following, aligned together so that I can give them the same title:

[image]

This is what I have written:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'APC': CPC1,'PC':IL1, 'AE': BP1, 'Hidden Dimension': x})
df_long1 = df1.melt('Hidden Dimension',var_name='Model',value_name='Correctly')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'APC': CPC2,'PC':IL2, 'AE': BP2, 'Hidden Dimension': x})
df_long2 = df2.melt('Hidden Dimension',var_name='Model',value_name='Correctly')

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'APC': CPC3,'PC':IL3, 'AE': BP3, 'Hidden Dimension': x})
df_long3 = df3.melt('Hidden Dimension',var_name='Model',value_name='Correctly')

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'APC': CPC4,'PC':IL4, 'AE': BP4, 'Hidden Dimension': x})
df_long4 = df4.melt('Hidden Dimension',var_name='Model',value_name='Correctly')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4)
fig.suptitle('{}'.format(dataset_name), fontsize=20)
ax[0] = sns.barplot(data=df_long1, x='Hidden Dimension', y='Correctly Retrieved (%)', dodge=True,hue='Model')
ax[1] = sns.barplot(data=df_long2, x='Hidden Dimension', y='Correctly Retrieved (%)', dodge=True,hue='Model')
ax[2] = sns.barplot(data=df_long3, x='Hidden Dimension', y='Correctly Retrieved (%)', dodge=True,hue='Model')
ax[3] = sns.barplot(data=df_long4, x='Hidden Dimension', y='Correctly Retrieved (%)', dodge=True,hue='Model')

ax[0].set_title('100 Examples')
ax[1].set_title('250 Examples')
ax[2].set_title('500 Examples')
ax[3].set_title('1000 Examples')

ax[0].set_xlabel('Hidden Dimension',fontsize = 12)
ax[1].set_xlabel('Hidden Dimension',fontsize = 12)
ax[2].set_xlabel('Hidden Dimension',fontsize = 12)
ax[3].set_xlabel('Hidden Dimension',fontsize = 12)

ax[0].set_ylabel('Correctly Retrieved (%)', fontsize = 15)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Correctly Retrieved (%)', fontsize = 15)
ax[2].set_ylabel('Correctly Retrieved (%)', fontsize = 15)
ax[3].set_ylabel('Correctly Retrieved (%)', fontsize = 15)
```

And this is (sadly) the output. What have I done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `ax` argument to `sns.barplot`:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for df, ax in zip([df_long1, df_long2, df_long3, df_long4], axs):
    sns.barplot(data=df, x='Hidden Dimension', y='Correctly Retrieved (%)', dodge=True,hue='Model', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Would you know how to add error bars to the above graph? So, let's assume i also know the variance of the data, how can i generate something like the following: 
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html